# minitoc don't work when i put package glossarie

Tags: table-of-contents, glossaries, minitoc

minitoc don't work where i put \printglossary why ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report} %We are creating a report

\usepackage[nopostdot,nogroupskip,style=super,nonumberlist,toc,automake,toc]{glossaries} %Load glossaries package

\makeglossaries

%Here we define a set of example acronyms
\newglossaryentry{Aaa}{name={AAA},description={First abbreviation}}
\newglossaryentry{Bbb}{name={BBB},description={Second abbreviation}}
\newglossaryentry{Ccc}{name={CCC},description={Third abbreviation}}

\usepackage{minitoc}
\begin{document}

\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

\printglossary[title={List of Abbreviations}] %Generate List of Abbreviations


\chapter{Sample Chapter}
\minitoc
\newpage
\section{me}
Here we are using the first abbreviation \gls{Aaa}. This is our second abbreviation \gls{Bbb}. The last one is \gls{Ccc}

\end{document}
```

please help me !!

Comment: your example works fine for me. Is your tex system up-to-date?

Comment: indeed I don't use a system but the site overleaf

Comment: Actually it doesn't in a current system either, but the minitoc disappears only after the third compilation. Because of your glossary, minitoc gets confused about the chapter numbers, you need to adjust the counters with `\printglossary[title={List of Abbreviations}] \mtcaddchapter`.

Comment: thanks it works